# Why mmenu generates "Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:" when clicked on a link?

Tags: mmenu

I am working to implement mmenu on my site, but every time I click on a link inside the menu, I get the following error in FireBug:

Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [clicked link]

Ideas?

Comment: Does this issue persist in the latest version? There have been a couple of bugfixes.